# Base64 Encoding Image

Tags: php, encoding, base64, opensearch

I am building an open search add-on for Firefox/IE and the image needs to be Base64 Encoded so how can I base 64 encode the favicon I have?

I am only familiar with PHP

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As far as I remember there is an xml element for the image data. You can use this [website](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to encode a file (use the upload field). Then just copy and paste the data to the XML element.

You could also use PHP to do this like so:

```
 <?php
        $im = file_get_contents('filename.gif');
        $imdata = base64_encode($im);      
?>
```

Use [Mozilla's guide](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox) for help on creating OpenSearch plugins. For example, the icon element is used like this:

```
<img width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,imageData</>
```

Where `imageData` is your base64 data.

Comment: base64_encode in this case will only encode the image's "resource handle", I believe, if anything at all. You would need to read in the file's actual contents. Just using that base64 encoder website should work, though.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. `$im` is a `resource` and I'm getting an error `base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

Comment: The above comments were referring to a previous edit, hakre fixed my mistake. @stevether this should now work.

Comment: `<img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,imageData" width="16" height="16">`Where `imageData` is your base64 data worked to show it for me, I am in Chrome

Answer (score 14):

```
$encoded_data = base64_encode(file_get_contents('path-to-your-image.jpg'));
```

Comment: @davidcorda - Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score 9):

My synopsis of [rfc2397](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt) is:

Once you've got your base64 encoded image data put it inside the <Image></Image> tags prefixed with "`data:{mimetype};base64,`" this is similar to the prefixing done in the parenthesis of `url()` definition in CSS or in the quoted value of the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in [X]HTML. You can test the data url in firefox by putting the `data:image/...` line into the URL field and pressing enter, it should show your image.

For actually encoding I think we need to go over all your options, not just PHP,
because there's so many ways to base64 encode something.

1. Use the `base64` command line tool. It's part of the GNU coreutils (v6+) and pretty much default in any [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org), [L](http://debian.org)[i](http://ubuntu.com)[n](http://opensuse.org/)[u](http://gentoo.org)[x](http://linux.org), [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sf.net) install, but not the BSDs I tried. Issue: `$ base64 imagefile.ico > imagefile.base64.txt`
2. Use a tool that features the option to convert to base64, like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sf.net) which has the feature under plugins->MIME tools->base64 Encode
3. Email yourself the file and view the raw email contents, copy and paste.
4. Use a [web](http://makcoder.sourceforge.net/demo/base64.php) [form](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp).

A note on mime-types:
I would prefer you use one of `image/png` `image/jpeg` or `image/gif` as I [can't find](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/) the popular `image/x-icon`. Should that be `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`?
Also the other formats are much shorter.

compare 265 bytes vs 1150 bytes:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAVFBMVEWcZjTcViTMuqT8/vzcYjTkhhTkljT87tz03sRkZmS8mnT03tT89vTsvoTk1sz86uTkekzkjmzkwpT01rTsmnzsplTUwqz89uy0jmzsrmTknkT0zqT3X4fRAAAAbklEQVR4XnXOVw6FIBBAUafQsZfX9r/PB8JoTPT+QE4o01AtMoS8HkALcH8BGmGIAvaXLw0wCqxKz0Q9w1LBfFSiJBzljVerlbYhlBO4dZHM/F3llybncbIC6N+70Q7OlUm7DdO+gKs9gyRwdgd/LOcGXHzLN5gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv///////////2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb///////////9mZmb/ZmZm//////////////////////////////////////////////////////9mZmb/ZmZm////////////ZmZm/2ZmZv//////ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv//////ZmZm/2ZmZv///////////2ZmZv9mZmb//////2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb/ZmZm/2ZmZv9mZmb//////2ZmZv9mZmb///////////9mZmb/ZmZm////////////////////////////8fX4/8nW5P+twtb/oLjP//////9mZmb/ZmZm////////////////////////////oLjP/3eZu/9pj7T/M2aZ/zNmmf8zZpn/M2aZ/zNmmf///////////////////////////////////////////zNmmf8zZpn/M2aZ/zNmmf8zZpn/d5m7/6C4z/+WwuH/wN/3//////////////////////////////////////+guM//rcLW/8nW5P/x9fj//////9/v+/+w1/X/QZ7m/1Cm6P//////////////////////////////////////////////////////7/f9/4C+7v8xluT/EYbg/zGW5P/A3/f/0933/9Pd9//////////////////////////////////f7/v/YK7q/xGG4P8RhuD/MZbk/7DX9f//////4uj6/zJh2/8yYdv/8PT8////////////////////////////UKbo/xGG4P8xluT/sNf1////////////4uj6/zJh2/8jVtj/e5ro/////////////////////////////////8Df9/+gz/P/////////////////8PT8/0944P8jVtj/bI7l/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////2yO5f8jVtj/T3jg//D0/P///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////3ua6P8jVtj/MmHb/+Lo+v////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////D0/P8yYdv/I1bY/9Pd9///////////////////////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the following example:

```
// First get your image
$imgPath = 'path-to-your-picture/image.jpg';
$img = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgPath));
echo '<img width="100" height="100" src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. $img .'" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

Google led me to [this](http://fr.php.net/base64_encode) solution (base64_encode). Hope this helps!

Comment: yes I know how to encode it but how to get just the image data in there for it to be encoded.