# css zebra stripe background without image

Tags: css

possible to use css to have zebra stripe as background without using image?

Comment: More information please. The document background, div background, ul, table?

Comment: You don't happen to have a mock-up of what you're looking for? "Zebra" pattern is awfully vague.

Comment: @EboMike, zebra line is just an example. i just wonder possible to put pattern on div without image

Comment: Somebody already provided a gradient as an example. Please define "pattern".

Comment: @EboMike, have a look at stackoverflow button on top of this page http://careers.stackoverflow.com/?campaign=PrettyHeader  . but this one using image for background

Comment: http://css3wizardry.com/2010/08/19/css3-gradients-and-patterns/ I think that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what you're after, but I would suggest maybe looking into Base64 encoded images in css

[Base64 Encoding Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image)

or alternatively using canvas or the svg namespace to draw it yourself

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, with something like

```
ul li {
   background-color: #fff;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #efefef;
}
```

See:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions

---

**Edit**

You really should've stated clearly what you meant by zebra strips ;)

If you need gradient backgrounds without using images, see:

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/

Basically, the syntax you'll be using will look something like:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff, #999);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, #fff, #999);
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient
http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/

For more details

Comment: but i want to put the zebra pattern on one "div" , make it look like button

Comment: @Yi Jiang,  i want solid zebra line not gradient

Answer (score 1):

Not really in the context I think you are referring to. You can use CSS3 selectors to target alternating items.

```
ul li {
 background-color:#000;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Even though you stated no image, the best solution would be to use a 1 pixel wide image with 2 rows that you repeat across x and y axis.

Comment: but i want to put the zebra pattern on one "div" , make it look like button