# Repeat a single CSS object

Tags: html, css

I want to make a zebra-like pattern with pure CSS. The one working has multiple instances of a span to generate the repeat. [Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/troymeren/6v3QS/).

```
<div id="wrap">    
 <span class="one"></span>
 <span class="two"></span>
 <span class="three"></span>
 <span class="four"></span>
 <span class="five"></span>
</div>
```

​
I know that this would be easier with an x-repeating stripe but I want to know **if it is possible to make with pure CSS** without using multiple instances of a `<span>` or `<div>` like:

```
<div id="wrap">    
 <span></span>
</div>

#wrap span {
 background: #000;
 /* stripe shape coordinates */

 repeat: x-repeat; /* something like this */
}
```

Comment: The answers you have are correct, but realistically I would assign a class to every other element server-side. Relying on CSS3 selectors is still not viable in most professional cases.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. 
I'm trying to learn pure CSS graphics and I  got stuck with the zebra pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664224/css-zebra-stripe-background-without-image) is what you're looking for, and particulary something like [this](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/08/19/css3-gradients-and-patterns/). It's css3 gradients used to make patterns. Basically, you create a pattern for the background, and then let that pattern repeat. However, older browsers won't work, but I don't know if that's an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I've been looking for exactly.
I didn't know that gradients can be used like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind dropping support for old browsers, you can use `:nth-child()`:

```css
#wrap span:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#000}
```

[MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo):

```
span:nth-child(2n+1) /* represents every odd-numbered child of its parent */
span:nth-child(odd)  /* same */
```