# Pass dynamic image from Flex to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, image, arrays

Need to:

1) Create bytearray from BitmapData in Flex

2) Pass this bytearray (or maybe converted to string with b64) to php script

3) Convert this bytearray again to image in PHP and show it.

How to do this?

Comment: You're on the right track. I know how to do the opposite of what you want (fetch an image with PHP and send it to Flex). You'll want to use the `base64_decode`/`base64_encode` functions in PHP. But what do you mean by "show it in PHP" ?

Comment: Show this image on the screen in web page.

Comment: Why does this sound like one of those can you do this for me questions?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a HTTPService to do that, you can fill out the `headers` property with the correct `content-type` ... you might want to look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type