# imagejpeg() function won't output the image

Tags: php, gd

Ok, so I'm learning how to use the GD library of PHP to generate polls, images, etc.. The thing is that when it comes to the image output using the `imagejpeg` function, nothing shows on the screen. For this exercise, I am typing text on a HTML forum, which needs to be put on an image using the GD library, basically putting text on an image. It's pretty straight-forward, I just don't understand why my image won't show. Below is both the HTML form code and the PHP code.

HTML form:

```html
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Create Buttons </title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action ="button.php" method ="post">
            <p> Type button text here </p>
            <input type="text" name="button_text" size ="20" />
            <p> Choose button color: </p>
            <input type ="radio" name="color" value="red"> Red <br>
            <input type ="radio" name="color" value="green"> Green <br>
            <input type ="radio" name="color" value="blue"> Blue <br>
            <input type ="submit" value ="Create Button" />
        </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php
Header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$button_text = $_POST['button_text']; var_dump($button_text);
$color = $_POST['color']; var_dump($color);
if(empty($color) || empty($button_text)) {
    echo " Could not create image - form not filled correctly";
    exit;
}
$path = $DOCUMENT_ROOT."/uploads/$color-button.jpg";
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg ($path);
$width_image = imagesx($im);
$height_image = imagesy($im);

$width_image_wo_margins = $width_image-(2*18);
$height_image_wo_margins = $width_image-(2*18);

$font_size = 33;
putenv('GDFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts');

$fontname = getenv('GDFONTPATH') . '\comic.ttf';
if(!is_file($fontname)) {
    die( "Missing Font");
}

do {
    $font_size--;
    $bbox = imagettfbbox($font_size,0,$fontname,$button_text);
    $right_text = $bbox[2];
    $left_text = $bbox[0];
    $width_text  = $right_text -$left_text;
    $height_text = abs($bbox[7] - $bbox[1]);
}

while($font_size > 8 && ( $height_text > $height_image_wo_margins || $width_text > $width_image_wo_margins));

if ( $height_text > $height_image_wo_margins || $width_text > $width_image_wo_margins) {
    echo "Text given wil not fit on button.<br />";
} else {
    $text_y = $width_image/2.0 - $width_text/2.0;
    $text_x = $height_image/2.0 - $height_text/2.0;

    if($left_text < 0) {
        $text_x += abs($left_text); //add factor for left overhang.  
    }
    $above_line_text = abs($bbox[7]);
    $text_y += $above_line_text;
    $text_y -=2;
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
    imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $text_x, $text_y, $white, $fontname, $button_text);

    imagejpeg($im, NULL,75); 
}
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Most probably the image is corrupted along the line. These image function may return false if it fails to do its job. Trying checking the values return after function calls. Also dont forget to turn on all error reporting temporarily to see if any error will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `var_dump` statement.

That is sending text to your output.  The `imagejpeg()` call is probably creating the image fine, but it will not render with the `var_dump` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing because you haven't actually done anything to display the image. While this script creates an image, you need another to actually call this just as in vanilla HTML.

This topic has been covered on SO previously: [PHP GD Library: Output an image and text on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338695/php-gd-library-output-an-image-and-text-content-on-same-page).

I also recommend that you work through a tutorial or two. There are dozens available if you do a quick search. I won't post any here at the risk of turning this into a "20 Great GD Tutorials" post.

Comment: I have called the function imagejpeg .. Can you suggest what I should do actually display it ?  Thanks

Comment: You seem to be mixing two concepts. GD is usually used to either manipulate or create an image on disk (e.g., after an upload), or to actually create dynamic images using the JPEG header. You have the JPEG content header, so your script should only contain code to create an image. Say your script is called "foo.php", you would then use that in an img tag -- `<img src="foo.php"/>` -- as if it were a normal image. Try it. I'm not kidding!

Comment: But that's for a separate if statement ... Does that actually affect the header at all ?

Comment: Once you have `Header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` in your script, you're done. It's set as an image mime type. No amount of conditions will change that.

Comment: I see .. So I actually forgot to add the <img src html tag for the image to be displayed .. that's what you meant ?  then should I use the imagejpeg function in the bottom .. That's actually code from a PHP book .. It's supposed to be working :|

Answer (score 0):

Remove the echo statements when using header('Content-Type: image/jpeg') that worked for me

Comment: I never used echo statements using the header .. Look at the code above , there's no echo statements by the header.

Comment: Erm, just the presence of an echo won't break it, that will only be executed if there's a specific error. OP, this is not your problem.

Comment: @KaviSiegel Nothing still get output ...I need help