# Reading all Colors from an Image to convert it to CSS

Tags: php, image, css

Im trying to make a Image to CSS convertor, which works in PHP.

I have tried looking at the javascript convertor at:
http://codepen.io/blazeeboy/pen/bCaLE

I see that it make it into a canvas element and scans each pixels for the color, which would not make it possible the same way in PHP.

Comment: are you looking to base64 encode the image?

Comment: If you're looking to create Data URIs (see [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples)), then all you need to do in PHP is use `base64_encode` (see [discussion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#110868)). You won't need to read the pixel data, because you're just converting the image file to a ASCII format.

Comment: If you are trying to base64 encode an image for use in css, this link may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image

Comment: No, it is not just base64 encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PHP's GD2 functions, such as [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/imagecreatefrompng) and [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/imagecolorat).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) I got it fixed this way.