# PHP: How can I create a (PNG, JPEG or GIF) image and encode it directly in base 64 without saving it?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a script that creates an image. I have to make a common format like GIF, JPEG or PNG out of it and convert it to base 64, later on.

When doing this, I do not want to save the image on the server, nor I want any browser output.
So imagepng() seems not right command for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image

Comment: I do not need to load an image. The Image is drawn by a PHP script using JSON data.

Comment: you should note while this is possible, the last i checked internet explorer didn't care much for it.

Comment: I use the signature pad script, which uses canvas and falls back to flash canvas. It generates JSON in a hidden field which will be used to draw the image on the server side. ( http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, you can always do this:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($resource);
$png = base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: Interesting method. I am a little scared to use this, because my script will rund inside of a content management system.

Comment: I tried it. It works. It seems to be the only way to do this.