# Showing image with php and fancy box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

I'm showing my images with php.

```
function showImage( $id = 0 ){

        $img = $this->db->where('id' ,  $id )->get('images');
        $src = base_url('files').'/'.$img['filename'] ;

        $ext = explode('.' , $img['filename']);

        switch( end($ext) ) {
            case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
            case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
            default:
        }

        header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
        echo file_get_contents($src);
}
```

It works fine when I put address directly in the browser , but when I call it with fancybox 
it show a very big screen with nothing in it and I get lots of

```
���F���!1AQ"aq� 2��#B��R�3�$r��Cb�%&4c�����������������������#�������!1AQa2"q������?��P�����������
```

In the firebug in response to fancybox ajax request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image Maybe this will help you

Comment: You're exploding the filename but then testing the array, instead of the last index of the array $ext which is the actual file extension. YOu want switch($ext[count($ext) - 1])

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found fancybox doesn't always play well with dynamically generated images. My solution was a rewrite in .htaccess. I was using .net with isapi rewrite but the rule will be similar. It was something like

/([0-9])/([^/.]+).(jpg|gif|jpeg|png)$ /image.ashx?id=$1&filename=$2&extension=$3

This did the trick for me. (the image.ashx would be your php file)

Comment: thanx i'm going to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

i've solve it by adding

```
  "type":"image"
```

to fancybox config

Comment: We normally prefer the tray/error method first instead of reading the documentation ;) http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==> FAQ tab ==> No.5