# Sending Zip file via SOAP in PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have to send a file to a WSDL, the element is described in the WSDL as:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="theZipFile" type="s:base64Binary" />
```

How can I send the Zip file using SOAP Client? I have tried the following:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$params = array("theZipFile" => "file.zip");
$response = $client->theFunction($params);
```

But I don't get the expected response. I have tried using .Net and C# with the following code:

```
string filename = "file.zip";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
long numBytes = fi.Length;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
br.Close();
fs.Close();

XElement response = client.theFunction(data);
```

And it works without any problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you converting the byte stream to base 64 and did you verify that the zip file sent in the working code was still able to be opened?  I think the .NET is automatically converting to base64 in contrast to PHP where you would have to do that manually.

Comment: This should help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapClient wasn't sending the correct XML for some strange reason apparently was a problem with the definition.

Changed to use CURL.

```
function SOAPRawRequest($url, $postString, &$error) {
  $soap_do = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $postString); 
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     
    array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 
      "Accept: text/xml",
      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
      "Pragma: no-cache",
      "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/theFunction\"",
      'Content-Length: '.strlen($postString)
    ));

  $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
  $error = curl_error($soap_do);

  return $result;
}
```

Also changed `$params = array("theZipFile" => "file.zip");` to:

```
$content = file_get_contents("file.zip");
$content64 = base64_encode($content);
```

Comment: So was it the change to CURL or the actual encoding of the bytes to base64?  Seems as though the original code would have sent raw binary which would have destroyed/invalidated your XML.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a file name instead of file content to the soap call. Use

```
$params = array("theZipFile" => base64_encode(file_get_contents('path/to/a/file.zip')));
```